# Keep ASP .NET page from logging out

Tags: asp.net

I have a strange problem where the users of my application complain about the app timing out on them when there is now activity for awhile.

I try to reproduce this same problem and the application won't time out on me. I can keep it up on my machine for over an hour, go back to it and still works.

Any suggestions on whats going on?

Comment: What are your FormsAuthentication settings in your web.config?

Comment: I have none. I have <authentication mode="Windows"/> if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming David's link isn't able to help - it might be worth considering if the user could be knowingly (or unknowingly) clearing their cookies. Also, I'd consider if there could be any time changes taking place on the client.

Comment: Well they are walking away from the computer for awhile and then coming back.

Comment: Yeah.. It's been a while since I've done customer support, but rule #1 is never trust the user Verify everything they tell you. (even if it means looking over their shoulder for an 59 minutes to verify that it does time out in less than an hour)

Answer (score 1):

Check into the [Session.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx), and if you're using Forms Authentication, you need to worry about the [Forms Authentication](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/08/430011.aspx) timeout.

Based on  your description, it could be either or.

Here's a good article for dealing with session timeouts.

http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/07/aspnet-session-timeouts.html

Comment: I do have <sessionState timeout="15"></sessionState>